# PhpStorm Code Inspector: "Method not found" in Route File of Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

The *Code Inspector* of my PhpStorm 2016.1.2 (with Laravel Plugin installed) says about the following code.

## Code routes/api.php

```
<?php

$this->app['router']->group(
    ['namespace' => 'Foo\Access\Controllers'],
    function() {
        $this->app['router']->post('auth/login', ['uses' => 'AuthController@login']);
    }
);
```

## Errors

- Method 'group' not found in (at line 3)
- Method 'post' not found in (at line 6)

## Question

How can I tell PhpStorm that `$this-app['router']` references to `Illuminate\Routing\Router`?

Comment: Maybe its a hacky way but you can add a comment line like this `/** @var \Illuminate\Routing\Router */` to above that line.

Comment: Have you looked into Laravel's ide-helper? https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Comment: Change `$this->app['router']` into `Route::`?

Comment: @CanVural That didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @aynber A vendor package for an IDE? :(

Comment: @NicklasKevinFrank I always try to avoid using facades.

Comment: @schellingerht Yes. It's actually quite helpful for mapping classes for IDEs. You can add it in your composer.json to `require-dev`, so it's only installed in your development environment.

Comment: That didn't solve my problem. I installed Laravel IDE Helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was very simple. I changed the array access of the object.

```
<?php

    $this->app->router->group(
    ['namespace' => 'Foo\Access\Controllers'],
    function() {
        $this->app->router->post('auth/login', ['uses' => 'AuthController@login']);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `api.php` routes file is included by the `RouteServiceProvider.php` (on app/Providers) on a method called `mapApiRoutes` (see [source code](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L69)). You'll see a code similar to this:

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'api',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'prefix' => 'api',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/api.php');
    });
}
```

This means you can use a variable called `$router` instead of `$this->app['router']` on `api.php`. This, alone, is not sufficient for the IDE to realize what type the variable `$router` is, but you can do so with PHPdoc. Something like:

```
<?php

/**
 * @var \Illuminate\Routing\Router $router
 */
$router->group(
    ['namespace' => 'Foo\Access\Controllers'],
    function() use ($router) {
        $router->post('auth/login', ['uses' => 'AuthController@login']);
    }
);
```

Now, this has a downside, because since routes inside the  `->group` are defined in the closure, you'll need to send the `$router` variable through `use ($router)`.